# How can one show that (DI) , (JB) and (AC) concurrents on G?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

ABCD is a square , We add outside it two equilateral triangles ADJ and ABI 
How can I show that (DI) and (BJ) and (AC) occur in the same point ?
Here can we demontrate that saying that IGB and JGD are isometric on The line (AC) ?!
What about the circle ?! 
I added somthing ... G is the point of masse of IJC ??! 
Can someone give me a suggestion ?! I don't want the answee I have to work my mind ... THANKS

Comment: I have to use usual transformations in the plan

Comment: The construction is symmetric with respect to the $AC$ line, so $DI$ and $BJ$ intersect on $AC$.

Comment: Yeah I see thnk u so much